# Proper way to extract 3D points from Depth image

Tags: python, opencv, depth

I'm using the following code to extract the 3d points from the depth image,

```
def retrieve_3d_points(K , depth_image_path):
    depth_factor = 1000.0

    depth_img = cv2.imread(depth_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH) / depth_factor

    row, col = depth_img.shape

    pts3d = []
    fx = K[0][0]
    cx = K[0][2]

    fy = K[1][1]
    cy = K[1][2]

    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            depth = depth_img[i][j]
            x, y = i, j
            if depth > 0.0:
                x3D = (x - cx) * depth / fx
                y3D = (y - cy) * depth / fy
                z3D = depth
                pts3d.append([x3D, y3D, z3D])
            else:
                pts3d.append([-1, -1, -1])
    return pts3d
```

Unfortunately, the retrieve points are not so accurate in terms of scale. Am I retrieving properly?

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly generated from a camera distance, instead of normalized to a particular range.
You'll have to loop through it, to find the extents: minimum value, maximum value.

```
minimum, maximum = 0, 0
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        pixel = depth_img[i][j]
        if pixel < minimum:  minimum = pixel
        elif pixel > maximum:  maximum = pixel

extent = maximum -minimum
normalized = [ [], [] ]  ##  normalize values within range 0-1

for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        ##  subtract minimum from every point, then divide by extent
        normalized[i][j] = ( depth_img[i][j] -minimum ) /extent

---

scale = 255  ##  optional, if you expect a different range of values.  0-255
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        normalized[i][j] = ( depth_img[i][j] -minimum ) /extent *scale
```

Then run your `retrieve_3d_points()` on array with expected values.

Comment: It's possible cv2, numpy, et al, have such a normalize range function built-in.  I don't have all those modules memorized tho, so you'd have to hunt for it, or possibly someone else knows.  I suspect range is the reason though.